# What does earliest point mean here?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image: The parser repeats the offending line and displays a little 'arrow' pointing at the earliest point in the line where the error was detected. The error is caused by (or at least detected at) the token _preceding_the arrow.]

This screenshot is taken from Python Documentary. I wanted to know what does *earliest point* mean here? (I have marked it with a red line). Does it mean the first point where an error was detected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes- specifically, not just the earliest point, but *the earliest point on a line* where the syntax error occurred.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to upvote your answer but my low reputation on this site doesn't let me to do so.

Comment: No problem! There is at least one place where we all have a "low reputation" and no one there cares about what we think. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hey @GforOevOerD (forever good, I like that). Just to add to the answer by @Gary: the word "point" as you probably know by now has many meanings:

- a point in space - "The point you see on this map is where the robbery took place."
- a point in time - "I'll finish my homework at some point tonight."
- an argument - "She made a valid point about hiring another person for the team."
- purpose, reason - "There is no point in continuing with your lies - we know the truth."
- etc

So "the earliest point in the line where the error was detected" means "the *first location* (i.e. character) in the line where the error was detected"

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer also helped me a lot. But i can't upvote your answer due to low points of reputation.

Comment: Haha that's OK - I'm not doing this for the points.